# Exercises for continuum hypothesis and forcing

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, forcing

I am recently reading the third chapter, continuum problem, from *mathematical logic for mathematicians*(GTM53). I think the book is quite nice, but it doesn't have any exercises. I want to do some exercises to gain some more deep insight about the theory. Can anyone tell me where can I find, some exercises for this?

Answer (score 4):

Kenneth Kunen: Set Theory (Studies in Logic: Mathematical Logic and Foundations, new edition), 2011.

Thomas Jech: Set Theory (3rd Edition), 2006.

Comment: I heard Prof. Franklin Tall (University of Toronto) say " I always see a great improvement in my students after they have done all the problems in "Kunen ."